# Where can I see output of echo in electron-builder custom NSIS include script?

Tags: electron, nsis, uninstallation, electron-builder

I have created simplest electron app from official [Quick Start Guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start).
I am able to create installer also using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build)

Now I want to try `customUnInstall` macro of NSIS option given at https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis

My `installer.nsh` file is

```
!macro customUnInstall
  !echo "test output"
!macroend
```

My `package.json` file is

```
{
    "name": "my-electron-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": "your name",
    "description": "My Electron app",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^12.0.1",
        "electron-builder": "^22.10.5"
    },
    "build": {
        "nsis": {
          "include": "installer.nsh"
        }
      }
}
```

Where can I see output of line `!echo "test output"` in `installer.nsh`?
Currently I am not seeing any output message or dialogue in case of running uninstaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!echo` prints a message in the compiler, use `DetailPrint` or `MessageBox` to display something in the installer/uninstaller.

e.g.

```
!macro customUnInstall
  MessageBox MB_OK "Test output"
!macroend
```

Comment: `MessageBox` is working fine but not `DetailPrint`

Comment: DetailPrint is only visible on the InstFiles page (you might have to click the show details button on that page)

Comment: do you have any idea on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66601182/electron-builder-custom-nsis-include-script-macro-not-working

Comment: From the moment the "customInstall" is called DetailPrint does not work anymore on my side as well . It's not about show detail as I have ShowInstDetails show and ShowUninstDetails show and it worked well before entered this macro. For me I needed to add SetDetailsPrint both on top of it

Comment: @Omnia69 Electron builder must be turning the print off before calling the macro for whatever reason. NSIS itself never calls SetDetailsPrint.