# electron-builder custom NSIS include script macro not working

Tags: node.js, electron, windows-installer, nsis, electron-builder

I have created a [electron](https://www.electronjs.org) desktop app and created a installer using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/).

Now I want to try macro like `customInstall` and `customUnInstall`

My `installer.nsh` file is

```
!macro customInstall
  MessageBox MB_OK "Test output 1"
!macroend

!macro customUnInstall
  MessageBox MB_OK "Test output 2"
!macroend
```

My `electron-builder` config is

```
"build": {
    "nsis": {
      "include": "installer.nsh"
    },
    "mac": {
      "icon": "build/icon.png"
    },
    "win": {
      "icon": "build/icon.png"
    }
  }
```

But this is not working for me. I have confirmed that `installer.nsh` is working by introducing error in that.
What I am missing to make it working?

Answer (score -1):

Actually everything is working fine at this moment.

Your macros **customInstall** and **customUnInstall** are defined correctly, but they are not called from any place.

Simply *call* them from appropriate section/function/place/situation/etc.

Their execution depends entirely on you, there are no automatic call of them from script.

Comment: no need to call them manually from anywhere. `electron-builder` is doing that job by using these macros. `installer.nsh` is part of `electron-builder` config

Comment: OK, show the resulting .nsi script how the customInstall and customUnInstall macros are called.

Comment: I understand how it is designed, I wanted to see the real result, whether the electron-builder generated the .nsi script file and included files correctly. If not (you can check that by yourself if your scripts cannot be published) then you need to call that macros manually...

Comment: In the question I have already mentioned that I have `installer.nsh` is getting picked up and running by putting error like `MessageBox MB_OK ""Test output 1"` in it. This means `macros` are getting called

Comment: Do you see the message box with text "Test output 1" shown when installer is executed? If yes then your script is working and the macros are called, otherwise NO.
When you make an error like MessageBox MB_OK ""Test output 1" that means the script is not compiled correctly, but it has nothing to do with calling the macros from within the installer.